# Insert Login Page in XCode generated single view application

Tags: ios, authentication, storyboard

I am trying to present a login page before the user gets to the application. I created my app with XCode `Single View Application` option, and when I look in the `AppDelegate.m` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods, it's empty.

If I run the app, it goes straight to the view generated in the storyboard. Where should I insert the login page?

More info:
I want to check whether the user is already logged in or not, if logged in, it will just go straight to the normal view generated with xcode, if the user is not logged in, I want to display a login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the logic to decide whether to present the login controller in the viewDidAppear method of your initial controller. If the user is not logged in, present the login view controller with animation set to NO -- the login screen will be the first thing the user sees.

Comment: What I have already done and it works is manually set the `rootviewcontroller` of the window to the loginViewController, then switch the rootviewcontroller to the initial controller when user is logged in (in the AppDelegate). Is one way more secure/better than the other? Also, where is the logic for the initial controller?

Comment: @doog, what you're doing is ok, though you get no animation when you switch view controllers (with my way, when you dismiss the modal login controller you can do that with animation). I don't understand your last sentence. What logic in the initial view controller are you asking about?

Comment: I mean where's the code that set the initial controller as the rootviewcontroller of the window? My understanding is that this should be set in the AppDelegate, but by default there's no code in the methods in AppDelegate.

Comment: @doog, When you use storyboards, the initial controller (the one with an arrow pointing to its left side) is automatically instantiated and made the window's root view controller.

Comment: Surely this should be in viewWillAppear, otherwise you see the other view first before the login page loads?

Comment: @MarkRamotowski, no you won't if you do it without animation, and viewWillAppear is still too early -- you'll get a warning about trying to present a view controller on a controller whose view is not in the window's hierarchy.

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:logingVC animated:NO];
When you say without animation, you mean there, when pushing the ViewController? Because, the previous screen still flashes and then this pops up in front. - Could it have something to do with me running on the simulator as opposed to on a device?

Comment: @MarkRamotowski, Yes, passing NO in the animation is what I mean. However, my answer is about presenting (modally), not pushing, but when I try it with a push, I don't see a flash of the first screen. The purpose of using the modal is because once you're done with it, you want it to go away and not be part of the hierarchy, so I wouldn't use a push for this situation.